# Cmake: link openscenegraph to my shared library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cmake, openscenegraph

I'm new in using CMake, and I need to link openscenegraph library to my shared library.

Part of code responsible for it looks like this:

```
add_library (MyLib SHARED ${${PROJECT_NAME}_sources})
target_link_libraries(MyLib ${OPENSCENEGRAPH_LIBRARIES})
```

Im finding osg like this:

```
find_package(OpenSceneGraph REQUIRED osgDB osgUtil osg osgViewer osgGA osgShadow)
include_directories(${OPENSCENEGRAPH_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${OPENSCENEGRAPH_DEFINITIONS})
```

And everything looks like it is linking, CMake isn't giving me any errors, but during building with Visual Studio 2010 I got errors like:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'osg/Node': No such file or directory
```

Usually I was finding answers to all my questions without asking them (this is my first question here).
This may be trivial, but can someone tell me what am I doing wrong, and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seems related to linking, but to compile. The error says that MSVC doesn't find the file 'osg/Node' in the list of included directories.

Somewhere in your source code, you probably have an include like

```
#include "osg/Node"
```

so compiler will search for a file called 'Node' in the directory called 'osg' in one of the 'include directories'.

In CMake, print the list of include dirs for OpenSceneGraph (after `find_package(OpenSceneGraph ...)`

```
message(STATUS "OSG Incl dirs: ${OPENSCENEGRAPH_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

then check this list. If it contains something like `C:/path/to/openscenegraph/include` then you should import Node using

```
#include "osg/Node"
```

If instead you have a folder for each module (ex: `C:/path/to/openscenegraph/include/osg`) so you must use

```
#include "Node"
```

If you don't want to modify includes in your code, then you have to add `C:/path/to/openscenegraph/include` in your include directories (from CMake script)

```
include_directories(C:/path/to/openscenegraph/include)
```